# I have a race program in C that always has the same winner no matter what

Tags: c, signals, semaphore

The following program is controlled by named semaphores and is supposed to do this:

1. The main process creates `N_PROC` children and an id is assigned to each child (**0** for the first child that has been created,**1** for the second one and so on).
2. Each children waits for a signal from their father by using `pause()`.
3. The main process sends his children a `SIGUSR1` signal.
4. Each child repeats this until they die: they open a file (the same file for all children), write their id, close the file and then sleep during a random number of milliseconds between 1 and 100.
5. Each second, the main process opens the same file as his children, counts the number of times each id is present (printing them as he reads them) and, if a child has written its id 20 times, declares that child the winner, sends a `SIGTERM` to all his children, waits for them to finish and then deletes the semaphores.

My problem is that no matter how many times I recompile or rerun the program the parent always prints the same thing and thus child number 2 is always the winner.

Thank you in advance.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SEM1 "/example_sem1"
#define SEM2 "/example_sem2"
#define SEM3 "/example_sem3"

#define FFILE "ejercicio9.txt"

#define N_PROC 3

int valor_semaforo(sem_t *sem) {
    int sval;

    if (sem_getvalue(sem, &sval) == -1) {
        perror("sem_getvalue");
        sem_unlink(SEM1);
        sem_unlink(SEM2);
        sem_unlink(SEM3);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return sval;
}

int main(void) {
    sem_t *sem_write = NULL, *sem_read = NULL, *sem_count = NULL;
    pid_t pid[N_PROC];
    int i, numero, num[N_PROC], t;
    struct sigaction act;
    FILE *fp;
    srand(time(NULL) + getpid());

    if ((sem_write = sem_open(SEM1, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1)) == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("sem_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((sem_read = sem_open(SEM2, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1)) == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("sem_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((sem_count = sem_open(SEM3, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0)) == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("sem_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sigemptyset(&(act.sa_mask));
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }    

    for (i = 0; i < N_PROC; i++) {
        num[i] = 0;
        pid[i] = fork();
        if (pid[i] < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (pid[i] == 0) {
            pause();
            while (1) {
                sem_wait(sem_write);
                fp = fopen(FFILE, "a+");
                fprintf(fp, "%d ", i);
                fclose(fp);
                sem_post(sem_write);
                usleep(1 + (rand() % 100));
            }
        }
    }

    kill(0, SIGUSR1);
    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
        sem_wait(sem_read);
        sem_post(sem_count);
        if (valor_semaforo(sem_count) == 1)
            sem_wait(sem_write);
        sem_post(sem_read);

        fp = fopen(FFILE, "r");
        while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &numero) > 0) {
            printf("%d ", numero);
            fflush(stdout);
            for (i = 0; i < N_PROC; i++) {
                if (numero == i)
                    (num[i])++;
                if (num[i] == 20) {
                    printf("\nHa finalizado la carrera: el ganador es el proceso %d\n", i);
                    fflush(stdout);

                    act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
                    if (sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, NULL) < 0) {
                        perror("sigaction");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }    

                    kill(0, SIGTERM);
                    while (wait(NULL) > 0);
                    sem_close(sem_write);
                    sem_close(sem_read);
                    sem_close(sem_count);
                    sem_unlink(SEM1);
                    sem_unlink(SEM2);
                    sem_unlink(SEM3);
                    fclose(fp);
                    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    fp = fopen(FFILE, "w+");
    fclose(fp);

    sem_wait(sem_read);
    sem_wait(sem_count);
    if (valor_semaforo(sem_count) == 0)
        sem_post(sem_write);
    sem_post(sem_read);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that the result would be different every time?

Comment: All child processes will get precisely the same sequence of random numbers because you don't call `srand` with a different value in each one. You may want to add, after the `pause`, something like `srand(getpid() ^ (i * 1091));`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I checked with `printf` and the sequence does in fact change every time without having to call additional `srand`.

Comment: @ThomasJager Because it's an assignment for college and it says that I should simulate a random race between the child processes, so if the race is random I assume that the results should vary.

Comment: @VeraeldrAtmyrkr The problem is not that the sequence isn't different every time. The problem is that the sequence is precisely the same for each child process.

Answer (score 1):

You do not reset the `num` array before scanning the file. It happens that on your system the third child writes to the file first.

You should clear this array before parsing the file with:

```
memset(num, 0, sizeof num);
```

Or

```
for (i = 0; i < N_PROC; i++)
    num[i] = 0;
```

Comment: But I do do that just before I `fork`

Comment: Yes, but you must reset the counts before each scan of the output file, otherwise you count each entry multiple times.

Comment: Okay so I did that and also changed the `srand` in each child process but I still  get the same results each time...